# $.ajax success handler not being called

Tags: jquery, upload

I have this little AJAX script to handle a file upload:

```
$('body').on('change', '#uploadFile', function() {
    // Post-Data
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.files[0]);
    //data.append('foo', 1);

    // Ajax-Call
    $.ajax({
        url: "uploadUserpic.php",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(evt) {
            $("#message").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The file upload itself works but the message on success (in `#message`) is not shown. Why is this? Here is the litte PHP script for the upload:

```
$uploaddir = '../data/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File Upload OK.\n";
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong\n";
}
```

Comment: If the `success` handler doesn't get hit it means that the server side code is not returning a `200 OK` response. Check the network tab of the console to see exactly what the response of the request is, and hopefully determine the cause of the error.

Comment: Nothing....in network.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is to wrap the success function into an other function. Don't ask me why. Don't ask my why a man must spent hours to hours to read this important information:

```
  $('body').on('change', '#uploadFile', function() {

// Post-Data
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', this.files[0]);
//data.append('foo', 1);

// Ajax-Call
$.ajax({
    url: "uploadUserpic.php",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success : handleData 
});
});

function handleData(data) {
    $("#message").html(data);
//do some stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is the answer as it is logically no different to what you already had. My guess would be you accidentally solved an issue elsewhere in the code which was causing the problem, but at least you fixed it.

Comment: Hm...I only wrap the success-function like I say and then it works.

Comment: One thing I notice in the code of your question is that the `success` function takes a `evt` parameter, yet tries to set the `html()` with the `data` variable. That could be the original problem, although if that really was the case you would have had at least one error in the console.

Comment: That might be, but that thing work. So I don't touch it for now :-)